# Replacing " " with _ in AndroidStudio (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:** Hello, I am trying to replace a space within a string in my app using the following code:

```
String nationality1 = dataSnapshot.child("ean_data").child("nationality1").getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
nationality1 = nationality1.replace(" ", "_");
String svgNationality = "flag_" + nationality1;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I have seen a few similar questions that suggest that the
" " isn't a regular space but some other kind.

I think the following might work, but it's kind of a roundabout:

```
String nationality1 = dataSnapshot.child("ean_data").child("nationality 1").getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
String[] parts = nationality1.split(" ");
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1]; 
String _nationality = part1 + "_" + part2;
```

In this particular instance, the String is "united states" which I want to become "united_states".

**Question:** Is there any way to make this work with just .replace? The data is being drawn from firebase btw.

**Workaround** solution that encompasses strings with more than one space:

```
String nationality1 = "_" + dataSnapshot.child("ean_data")
        .child("nationality 1").getValue().toString().toLowerCase();

        if (nationality1.contains(" ")){
            nationality1 = nationality1.replaceFirst("_", "");
            String[] parts = nationality1.split(" ");
            nationality1 = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
                nationality1 = nationality1 + "_" + parts[i];
                 }
         }
         String svgNationality = "flag" + nationality1;
```

Comment: Does the second example *actually* work or do you just think it might? Your first example should work. The space in your code should be a regular space but perhaps the string from your database doesn't contain the characters that you think it does. (For example the space might be a Unicode "non-break space" or some other character that "looks" like a space.)

Comment: are the other characters just letters?are there strings like "born2 rule!"? If the strings contain letters which are of a known subset, you could exclude them and write the reg-ex.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn It does actually work, but I had to put an if statement in because not all of the nation's Strings have spaces. I'm not sure about the other part.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to convert any text to *snake_case* (or *lower_underscore*), it can get quite tricky if you consider all edge cases, so using a library might be your best bet.

One useful library on Java for this could be Google Guava's `com.google.common.base.CaseFormat`. You can see how to get started here: https://github.com/google/guava

You can look at the CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE method.

---

It is possible the issue is with the string using a different whitespace character, in which case you should look into *RegEx* with the `String.replaceAll` method, but this is unlikely.

Have you looked at the output the replace method is generating? Are you sure the issue is with the underscore not being replaced and not somewhere else on the svg file name? Which I assume is what you are trying to achieve.

Your second option would only work for countries with exactly 2 words in their name, but there are plenty of countries with more words than that (or single words). Also, it also requires that exactly 1 space character was used, and not any other whitespace characters.

Comment: Thank you! Noted. Yes, there are several countries with three spaces in them which makes it more complicated. I think I'm just going to handle it with the split method seems to work fine and not too slow.